# When is the Seed method called in a EF code first migrations scenario?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm new in a project and there is this class for the seed data:

```
 internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DAL.Context>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }
```

And this code to start the seed:

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
```

My question is: when is the `Seed` method called? Only when a user does `update-database` and the user doesn't have the database (basicly a new user), or also when the user with an existing database calls an `update-database`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seed method is used to have have some known static data like countries, states with initial database in code first. The Seed method will execute and populate these data every time the database is newly created.

Other use case is to use during the development/testing phase where you often need to recreate the database and populate database tables with sample data.

In other scenario if needs to add to that static data without dropping database(because it has real data) migrations Seed method used. Whenever you run the migration and update the database it will run the seed method. Needs to be careful here with long running Seed method as it runs every time the application starts.

Please go through [Database initializer and Migrations Seed methods](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/) for more explanation.

Comment: Your blog link is great! But I recommend that you correct your answer according to it: It all depends on the chosen initializer. Example: With initializer `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` your seed method will run whenever the application is started. Each new start of the IIS site of a Web API will run seed. Each change to web.config will run seed. I was quite surprised by this behavior but your blog post link made the reasons clear.

Comment: thanks @Jpsy, updated considering it was helpful to some.

Answer (score 22):

When it comes to the migrations `Seed()` method, coming from `DbMigrationsConfiguration` class, it's called every time when the `Update-Database` command is executed. Also when user calls it having existing database.

There is yet another `Seed()` method - it is a database initializer. It's invoked when database is creating and doesn't handle existing data (while seed from `DbMigrationsConfiguration` handles them, checking if specified entities exist).

Good to look up to [One Unicorn blog](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/) for more information.

Comment: Indeed, but when I create a new context within a unit test, is also runs Seed, giving me all my seed data in memory.