# Default value does not work in entity framework code first migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I stumbled upon a [entity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/overview) related question which I havn't found any answer for yet. When I try to add or alter a column while using [code first migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621.aspx) and set a default value for this column, I have the possibility to use either the [`defaultValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.columnmodel.defaultvalue.aspx) and/or the [`defaultValueSql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.columnmodel.defaultvaluesql.aspx) argument.

The official MSDN documentation writes following:

[**ColumnModel.DefaultValue:**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.columnmodel.defaultvalue.aspx)

> Gets or sets a constant value to use as the default value for this column.

[**ColumnModel.DefaultValueSql:**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.columnmodel.defaultvaluesql.aspx)

> Gets or sets a SQL expression used as the default value for this column.

Since different default value related questions on stackoverflow use different approaches, can someone please tell me when to use one or another?

For my specific use-case, I want to set a constant value of 4 for my database column, like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    this.AddColumn("dbo.Foo", "Bar", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 4));
}
```

Which results in the following:

[image: SQL Server Management Studio Table Designer]

Although this looks absolutely right, all the values of the data rows are set to zero...  Does anyone has any idea, why?

**EDIT:** Since @Vidmantas Blazevicius stated that default values will not be automatically applied, I tried to add following code to my `Configuration` class:

```
internal sealed class MigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE [dbo].[Foo] SET [Bar] = 4");
    }
}
```

But this also does not work. Do you guys have any idea how I set the default value after adding a new column?

Comment: it doesn't retrospectively add the default values, try inserting new record

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I have edited my question

Comment: Again - I don't think Seed is executed upon migration step - it is only when you create new database. You can add migration with `Add-Migration RunSqlScript` and then add your custom sql to update something.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius The strange thing is, that the seed method gets called every time the application starts :-/ I give your idea a try, thanks in advance!

Comment: It appears we were both right - there are two `Seed` methods - one gets called every time, another gets called on db initialization only. I would still go with the `Add-Migration` for your needs. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142107/when-is-the-seed-method-called-in-a-ef-code-first-migrations-scenario)

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Your proposed solution seems to work :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: No problems, I posted it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values aren't retrospectively added for existing records when adding new column to an existing table.

You can use `Add-Migration RunSqlScript` to add a new migration step and update the values in the new column with custom Sql.